# Error in webcomponents-lite.js

Tags: javascript, webpack, web-component

Receiving this error code in the console when trying to run the application.

```
webcomponents-lite.js:64Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null
    at webcomponents-lite.js:64
    at Object.549 (webcomponents-lite.js:74)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap a218042…:52)
    at Object.1242 (webcomponents.bundle.js:8)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap a218042…:52)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (bootstrap a218042…:23)
    at webcomponents.bundle.js:2
```

This is how I am instantiating the script with webpack:

```
    entry: {
               'polyfills': './src/polyfills.browser.ts',
               'vendor': './src/vendor.browser.ts',
               'main': './src/main.browser.ts',
               'webcomponents': './bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js',
 },
```

I get this error when using the webpack entry object, but if I instead use:

```
<script src="/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
```

on my index.html page it works, without error.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

EDIT::::

---

My coworker and I have the same version of bower_components and node_components, deleted and reinstalled everything. His works and mine did not. We noticed when we looked inside the bower_components file that we had different files and folders(No idea how). After sending the bower_components file that was in their project to me and I replaced my bower files with theirs, it worked......

Comment: not a lot here for us to go on in terms of figuring out the issue...

Comment: Can you please post the code where you are having this issue.

Comment: According to the git repo, its build is failing anyway, as of this moment:  https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/

Comment: Updated with entry example, are there any other pieces that you would like to see?

Comment: @Bobort it works when I use a script tag so i do not think it is a broken build.

Comment: What is written at webcomponents-lite.js:64?

Comment: @Supersharp   var src = script.getAttribute('src');

Comment: @Bobort I am having exactly the same issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't use the right version of `webcomponents-lite.js`. As @Bobort suggested the current branch is not working. Remove your installed version and then install the [last release](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/releases).

You can also get it using bower:

```
> bower i -S webcomponentsjs
```

Maybe the version you import in your  tag is not the same than the one you use in Webpack.